# Google sheets: Conditional Formatting. Turn Cell C red if Cell A and Cell B are not the same value

Tags: google-sheets

As stated in the title, I have three cells. We'll call them A B and C. I want to turn C red if B and C do not share a value. I can't seem to get the formula quite right and was hoping someone might be able to help ^~^

Editing to be more specific to what I need, because I realized a solution to the above question will not help entirely.

Here's a link to a copy of the document I'm working with.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-nR2J9a82ZDpOhWi0vee7LRxP03L96DYnML4Lawyw3g/edit#gid=449972452

So to specify what I'm trying to do:
When an ability is selected, that Trait Dependencies column is going to auto populate with any required traits as listed on another sheet. I need to turn the ability description box red if none of the Traits boxes hold the same value of the Trait Dependencies box

Answer (score 1):

use on range C1:C

```
=$A1<>$B1
```

---

### update:

```
=NOT(B23="Trait Name")*(NOT(REGEXMATCH(B23, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, I$43:I$80))))
```

[image]

Comment: Problem with using a range is that Cell A is B23, Cell B is I:43 and Cell C is C43. If I do it in range format, its not going to be able to pick out the right values

Comment: I tried this: `=IF(B23="certain text" AND I43="certain text", True, False)` but I guess `=IF()` can't check for more than one condition in sheets?

Comment: @BaileySinger can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: I also just realized I'm going to need it to check a range of cells for one portion of it not just one cell so this just got more complicated

Comment: Yeah I can, give me a moment. Its going to show reference errors because it references another sheet though so just ignore those ^~^

Comment: player0, the original post has been edited with both a link and more accurate information

Comment: @BaileySinger answer updated  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FFawWg1U1aLUCpZdCF35vG2LnYCs9UEdjr8YM1MxsLQ/edit#gid=449972452

Comment: Its close to what I'm looking for, just highlighting the wrong box red. I might be describing my needs poorly, and I do thank you for your efforts thus far!

What I need is for the Ability description box to highlight red if the text in the Trait Dependencies box doesn't match a value in any of the Trait boxes but remain white if the Trait Dependencies box has a value of "None"

Comment: `=if(isna(match(I43,B23:B40,0)),True, IF(I43="None", False, True))` is what I've come up with so far on my own, and it is indeed highlighting the box red when values don't match as they should, and leaving it white when they do. However I cannot get it to go back to white if the Trait Dependencies box value is "None" with that it would seem

Comment: @BaileySinger try: `=NOT(B23="Trait Name")*(NOT(REGEXMATCH(B23, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, I$43:I$80))))`

Comment: I got it!!! `=if(I43="None", False, if(isna(match(I43,B23:B40,0)),True, False))`

Comment: My next question would be is there a way to make that `(match(I43, B23:B40,0)` segment search for partial matches? Like just if the box contains that value amongst others?

Comment: Regarding your last comment, I suggest you ask a new question@BaileySinger

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer for documentation purposes:

```
=if(I43="None", False, if(isna(match(I43,B23:B40,0)),True, False))
```

#### Reference

- [IF function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364);
- [ISNA function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944);
- [MATCH function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378).